Convert RS232 signal to USB
I have an optical amplifier that uses RS232 and I want to convert to USB. I've purchased this chip, also here. There is little documentation on this chip and the supplier hasn't responded to questions. It's unclear to me if this chip can be used to convert RS232 to USB without an additional circuit. The part description states "USB to RS232", however, from the reviews it seems most people are using it to convert to TTL.
Can this part be used to convert RS232 to USB without other circuitry? If so, what pins do I need to connect from the RS232 side to the HiLetgo chip? In a couple places I've read that the Tx, Rx, and GND pins are all that need to be connected.
Unfortunately, I also don't have documentation on the amplifier signals and the supplier doesn't know either, so I'm assuming it's RS232 and I'll give it a try. Thanks for the help.
Amplifier Pins:
1: +3.3V 
2: GND
3: Rx
4: SCLK
5: MOSI
6: MISO
7: Tx
8: SS
HiLetgo Pins:
5V
VCC
3V3
TXD
RXD
GND

Do not assume. Measure the voltages on TX and RX pins compared to ground and then you will know.

OK it's a CH340 UART bridge, connect VCC to 5v to power it from USB,
I'm assuming it's all UART signals, (not RS232), when it's square pin headers like that it's usually UART.
Connect GND to GND between the two devices but connect RX to TX and TX to RX.
If the amplifier needs 3.3V you may be able to use 3V3 on the CH340 if it already has 3.3V don't connect that pin.

Thank you! The amp has another header where it gets +12V so i suspect it doesn't need the 3.3V. Given that, do I still connect HiLetGo VCC to the +3.3V on the amplifier?

Measure with your voltmeter to see if the amplifier makes 3.3v on the +3.3V terminal. (other terminal is GND) if it makes 3.3V (approx)  don't connect.  (but if you have documentation use that) - CH340 documetation here: https://www.wch-ic.com/downloads/CH340DS1_PDF.html
